# Konvajs Group Highlight with Border

Tags: javascript, konvajs

I am having 2 groups with circles or rectangles inside each group. I need to highlight the group on click, with a border in order for the user to know which group is active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of ways to do this. For example:

```
group.on('click', () => {
  // toggle selected, this is just our custom property
  group.isSelected = !group.isSelected;
  // hide or show selection box
  selectionRect.visible(group.isSelected);
  // set box size and position
  selectionRect.setAttrs(group.getClientRect()); 
  layer.draw();
})
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/nucopakijo/1/edit?html,js,output